# ros.org downtime?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

It seems that for a couple of times when I try to load ros.org (incl wiki, answers, etc), I get a 'not found' error. It was like the website is offline or something. Sorry I forgot the actual error.

Is it just me or is this common? The last time I had this was the whole day yesterday (around 9am - 5pm Malaysian time, GMT+8).

Arif

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135241/ros.org-downtime?/) by [Arif Rahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/12751/arif-rahman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They've been having some minor problems while upgrading the site, but I think those should be resolved.

The website status is available at http://status.ros.org/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0